# updating progress bar using Task parallel library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, task-parallel-library

I am trying to update the list of progress bars to show the image download progress using `Task Parallel Library` in `Xamarin.Forms`

For now I have written a block of code to simulate the download process by using a delay.

Here is my `Xaml` file where a `ListView` named `MediaList` resides with one caption and progress bar per item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ImageTask.View.ImageTaskView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MediaList}" CachingStrategy = "RecycleElement" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text = "{Binding mediaName}" FontSize="22" />
                            <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding mediaProgress}"></ProgressBar>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is my view model in which I have created one action block that takes the entire list of media object and tries to update the progress bar.

However, my main issue is I am not able to see the progress updated in my UI , so I don't know how shall I update my UI.

```
public class ImageTaskViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private IList<MediaInfo> _mediaList;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public IList<MediaInfo> MediaList
    {

        get { return _mediaList; }
        set
        {

            _mediaList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MediaList");

        }
    }
    public ImageTaskViewModel()
    {

       Action<IList<MediaInfo>> progressActionBlock = mediaInfoList =>
       {
           // infinite loop to simulate download
           while (true)
           {
               IEnumerator<MediaInfo> dataList = mediaInfoList.GetEnumerator();

               Task.Delay(2000).Wait();           

               while (dataList.MoveNext())
               {

                   MediaInfo mediaInfo = dataList.Current;

                   Debug.WriteLine("media name " + mediaInfo.mediaName + " progress " + mediaInfo.mediaProgress);


                   if (mediaInfo.mediaProgress == 1)
                   {
                       Debug.WriteLine("media name " + mediaInfo.mediaName + " Done ");
                       break;

                   }
                   else
                   {
                       mediaInfo.mediaProgress = mediaInfo.mediaProgress + 0.1;
                   }                       
               }                   
           }

       };

        var opts = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2

        };
        var progressAction = new ActionBlock<IList<MediaInfo>>(progressActionBlock, opts);           

        MediaList = new List<MediaInfo>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo();
            mediaInfo.mediaName = i.ToString();
            MediaList.Add(mediaInfo);

        }
        // Exectue Action block
        progressAction.Post(MediaList);
    }
}
```

Model of `MediaInfo`:

```
public class MediaInfo
{      
    public string mediaId { get; set; }
    public string mediaName { get; set; }
    public string mediaPath { get; set; }     
    public byte[] mediaStream { get; set; }
    public double mediaProgress { get; set; } = 0.1;              

}
```

Comment: All you need to do with this is to make `MediaInfo` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: FYI: My previous comment only applies if the sample code simulating your downloads behaves as you say it does.

Comment: but i have implemented `INotifiyPropertyChanged` in view model , so do you want to implement it in model too ?

Comment: Yes, right now the only 'Property' reporting changes is `MediaList` so the only notification that will be sent is if you completely _replace_ that list. Use   an `ObservableCollection` to get notified of collection changes and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the model to get notified of model changes. Whether or not a model should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or not depends on your architecture / design decisions, you could spin off a `MediaInfoViewModel` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` but that's outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your View model you don't have mediaProgress. You should add

```
    Double _mediaProgress;
    public Double mediaProgress{
        get{
            return _mediaProgress;
        } set{
            _mediaProgress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Email");
        }
    }
```

And then in your all method you use mediaProgress to set the progress.

Comment: my `mediaProgress` is inside the `mediaInfo` object as there are multiple progress bar and the entire object is bind with the `MediaList`

Comment: Ok, but in your ViewModel you don't binding mediaProgress to progress bar